# dataTables 1.10.4 : <object>.row is not a function error

Tags: jquery, datatables

Taking a cue from [Generated Content for a Column](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html), I used the same code to add a 'Delete' option as an extra column in my returned data. The 'Delete' option is showing up in the table, but when I click on it, I'm getting

> t.row is not a function

error. Below is the code that I'm using:

```
var t = $("table#available_profiles").dataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,         
            "ajax": "retrieve_profiles",
            "columns": [
                { data: 0 },
                { data: 1 },
                { data: 2 },
                { data: 3 },
                { data: 4 },
                { data: 5 },
                { data: 6 },
                {
                    data: null,
                    defaultContent: '<a href="#" class="remove">DELETE</a>',
                    orderable: false
                },
            ],          
            "columnDefs": [ {
                "searchable": false,
                "orderable": false,
                "targets": 0
            } ],
            "order": [[ 5, "desc" ]]
        });
        
                    
        $('table#available_profiles').on( 'click', 'a.remove', function () {
            var data = t.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data(); // error here
            alert( data[1] +"'s salary is: "+ data[ 7 ] );
            return false;
        } );
```

The table is getting drawn with the data processed from server side. So there are no missing js files or syntax errors with either the plugin js or the server side code.

From what I can tell, `t` is a global variable too. So it should be available inside the `a.remove` click function. But I'm running out of ideas on why this isn't working.

## UPDATE

Doing

> console.log(t);

is returning the following:
[image: Dt]

And I don't find the `row()` function anywhere. How could this be possible?

Comment: Hi, I'd check the jQuery selector $(...)  for $('table#available_profiles').on( 'click', 'a.remove', function () {     in the guide example tbody is also used: $('#example tbody')

Comment: Just to make sure that jQuery finds the tbody, try printing console.log ($('table#available_profiles tbody').length); before $('table#available_profiles tbody').on(..... if it prints value 1 then the code finds the tbody, if it's 0, then the selector isn't correct.

Comment: ok, within $('table#available_profiles tbody').on(.....  try printing the html of the selected item console.log ( $(this).html() );  I'm just thinking if something else than table row is being chose.

Comment: sorry correction, try with this: console.log ( $(this).parents('tr').html() );

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68956/discussion-between-jyrkim-and-asprin).

Comment: Looks ok in my opinion because it returns the content of table row. I think you are right you might be missing the t.row function

Comment: @jyrkim I solved it..it was such a minor issue. Thanks for your time though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I solved it. The problem was I was calling the plugin as

```
$("table#available_profiles").dataTable({....});
```

whereas it should have been

```
$("table#available_profiles").DataTable({...}); // notice the capital D
```